# Could [humor] and [humour] be synonymized?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, retag-request

I don't know which you'll want to keep, but they're definitely synonyms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. I kept [humor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humor) over [humour](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/humour) because the first was used 6 times, while the latter was only used once.

Comment: I'm not on english.sx a lot, so I don't know what policies on American vs. British spelling usually are here, but it seems appropriate to use only one of them for tags and have the other be synonyms.